# fancybox stretching to height of browser window when using an iframe with an swf that is 300x250

Tags: jquery, iframe, flash, fancybox-2

When running my site from localhost things work fine; I have fancyBox2 opening an iframe which loads in a swf that is 300x250. When running from local webserver fine, when I upload to actual site the fancyBox iframe stretches to the height of the browser window. Width seems to stay the same.

Here is the setup code in header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {

$("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox({

    update  :        true,
    openEffect       : 'elastic',
    closedEffect       : 'elastic',

    helpers: {
            overlay: {
                    locked: false
                    },
            title: {
                    type: 'inside'
                    },

    },
    autosize: true, 
    autoDimensions : true,

    beforeLoad : function() {                    
        this.width = parseInt(this.href.match(/width=[0-9]+/i)[0].replace('width=',''));  
        this.height = parseInt(this.href.match(/height=[0-9]+/i)[0].replace('height=',''));
    },
    titleFormat       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
        return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' +  (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + ' ' + title + '</span>';
    }
});
});
</script>
```

And here is the script calling the content:

```
<a rel="example_group" title="Elephant" class="iframe" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="http://mndzbl.com/samples/Flash/elephant_300x600_6_1.html?width=300&height=600">
```

This is from webserver: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILJWy.png

This is from localhhost webserver: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Jl2f.png

Comment: What about `autosize: false`? because you are trying to set the dimensions manually. BTW, `autoDimensions` and `titleFormat` are options for fancybox v1.3.x and not compatibles with v2.x

Comment: Well I took 'autoDimensions' out, but not sure what to do about titleFormat. Changed 'autoSize : false' but I am still getting the stretching. It's weird that it would be fine on LocalHost and then get wonky on different server. Maybe I am missing something

Comment: Also, I am not sure if setting the dimensions is the correct way to go. I am new to jquery and FancyBox, so am not sure what the best way to do this is

Comment: make sure you don't have other version of fancybox on the server that is interfering with the one in your local host. Additionally, try setting `fitToView` to `false`

Comment: I have made sure that scripts are both the same locally and on server. I am still getting a fancyBox window that stretches down to the bottom of the page. I have tried adding this:

    '.fancybox-outer, .fancybox-inner {
    height: auto !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
    position: relative;
    }'

But that makes the box so tight that it barely shows the content. hmm. The thing that makes me wonder is that it works from local webserver, but not correctly when uploaded to online webserver. Maybe a permission issue?

Comment: Seems this is where the problem exists:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ykas5zu2umdf5m/Screenshot%202014-08-22%2014.15.28.png?dl=0

it is setting that onload. Not sure where to fix that

Comment: The problem was in my misunderstanding that I needed to change 'fitToView' and other option from within the jquery.fancybox.js!

Live and learn. Here is what I changed to make the height not go to 9999px:

'
   autoSize   : false,
   autoHeight : false,
   autoWidth  : false,

   autoResize  : true,
   autoCenter  : !isTouch,
   fitToView   : false,
   aspectRatio : false,
   topRatio    : 0.5,
   leftRatio   : 0.5'

From within jquery.fancybox.js

Comment: You don't have to mess with the original jquery.fancybox.js file but change those options in your custom initialization script `$("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox({ // change options here })`

Comment: WEll I was trying those options but they didn't seem to work when I uploaded them to the server. Changing it in the jquery.fancybox.js file makes it work for some reason. Probably something that I am overlooking or have overlooked.